# Does Bootstrap version 3.4 compatible with JQuery version 3.4?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does Bootstrap version 3.4 compatible with JQuery version 3.4? Or do I need to upgrade to version 4 of Bootstrap?

I cannot use lower versions of JQuery before version 3.4 because according to our test software they contain vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the official bootstrap site says to check bower.json which states to use version above 1.9 and less than 3 but the support was added later for jquery 3 and is here [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/20338) . Also check the issue [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16834).